# Laravel trying to save $appends attributes

Tags: php, laravel, serialization, model, laravel-6

I am coding on Laravel 6, and stumbled up on this problem. I have `accessors` for a field that i need in my model in some cases, but **it does not exist in my database**. As i read in documentation, the variable `$appends` make the field in question to be serialized with the model, but not saved in database.

Then, **when i update or save entries** of the specific model in database, Laravel gives me back an error saying that `field x is not present in field list`. I searched here, googled a lot, but didn't found any answer.

This `pluggable_data` field is not sent by client-side. I create it on server-side because i need its information to do some tasks. But it is not relevant enough to create a column in DB just to store it.

Model

```php
    /**
     * @var array|null
     */
    protected $appends = [
        'pluggable_data'
    ];

    /**
     * @param array $pluggableData
     */
    public function setPluggableDataAttribute(array $pluggableData)
    {
        $this->attributes['pluggable_data'] = $pluggableData;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getPluggableDataAttribute(): array
    {
        return $this->attributes['pluggable_data'] ?? []; //  Sometimes there is no pluggable data, then i return an empty array
    }
```

Where the error occurs

```
    $activity->setRegisterDate($fields['register_date']);
    $activity->setExtraAttribute($fields['extra']);
    $activity->update(); <----- Here

    return $activity;
```

The error:
`SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'pluggable_data' in 'field list'`

Summarizing what i want (in case that you have a better idea): i want a field that will be present in model serializations, even if it is an empty array, but that does not be saved on database.

Comment: What's the name of the database column and in which line does your error occour?

Comment: Hello! pluggable_data does not have a correspondent database column. It is just a temporary field stored in model, that gets discarded. I edited the question showing exactly where the error is being triggered.

Comment: In this case, I'd remove that field either on client-side before sending or on server-side before calling `update()`

Comment: I will edit the question to make it more clear, sorry if i did not make myself clear

Comment: try to replace `$this->attributes['pluggable_data']`  to other variables.Eg:this._ pluggable_data.In laravel the attributes maybe need to save to database

Comment: Worked! Can you write a normal answer so i can mark it as the correct, please?

Comment: Did you tried ```$activity->save();``` instead of ```$activity->update();``` before solving your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @nay said in the comments, all i had to do was to replace the `$this->attributes['pluggable_data']` by a real variable, like `$this->pluggable_data`. This way, Laravel will not think that it is a database column